# Scroll to selected li in a scrollable ul

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have an scrollable ul with a fixed height and lis of height 40px inside it. Once an li is selected I want it to scroll to the mid point of the scrollable ul. How to do this using js since i'm trying to implement it in an angular application

onselect I'm trying to scroll the ul so that the selected li is scrolled to the mid point of the visible part of the ul. tried something like this below but no luck.

```
<ul id="record-selector-list">
        <li id="{{'record-selector-row-' + i}}" #scrollItem *ngFor="let row of getRecords();let i=index;" class="record-selector-elem" (click)="selectPart(i)">
            
        </li>
</ul>
```

```
public selectPart(index: number) {
        var ulElement = document.getElementById('record-selector-list');
        var liElement = document.getElementById('record-selector-row-' + index);

        const midpoint = window.innerHeight / 2;
        const scrollToPosition = midpoint - liElement.getBoundingClientRect().top

        ulElement.scrollTop = scrollToPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `const midpoint = window.innerHeight / 2;` - why are you working with the _window_ height there, when it is the UL that is scrollable?

Comment: Have you looked into [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) yet?